# Can Visual Studio Code with OmniPascal handle bdsproj files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnipascal

I have a couple of projects with bdsproj files and I know they were created with Borland Delphi 2005. Is there a way to open these projects in Visual Studio Code? What settings must be present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for `.bdsproj` files in OmniPascal.
You can load the corresponding `.dpr` files of the projects in order to get code completion etc but there is no support for automatic generation of build tasks.